# UI5 app crashes searching for deployed resources while served locally

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I am using the UI5 Tooling (version 2.14.9) in order to serve locally a project along with its custom library. Both projects are developed with OpenUI5 version 1.84.
My `ui5.yaml` is configured as follows (only relevant parts are reported)

```yaml
specVersion: "2.6"
metadata:
  name: "launchpad"
type: module
resources:
  configuration:
    paths:
      /my/app/: packages/my_app/webapp
      /resources/library/: packages/library/src/my_library
server:
  customMiddleware:
    ........
    - name: ui5-middleware-simpleproxy
      afterMiddleware: compression
      mountPath: /XMII/
      configuration:
        baseUri: "http://ip:port/XMII/"
        username: "user"
        password: "pw"
```

In my `index.html`:

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
    "my.app": "./",
    "my.library": "/resources/library"
  }'
  ...
></script>
```

The app crashes because it tries to load **some** of the library files on the deployment server rather than locally and gives me a `404 - File not found` error. The library is fully served by the "`ui5 serve`" command (also the files that the app is trying to reach on the server) and a lot of its files are correctly loaded from the local directory so I can't find a motivation for this behavior.
I'm not in a Fiori environment (I'm using VSCode and not SAP BAS) and I triple checked namespaces when importing in the app files from library.

**EDIT**

I found a partial solution which confuses me **a lot**: I added in my bootstrap script a new alias pointing towards the same resource and changed the reference (only for my crashing imports) and now all files are loaded locally.
But why????

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..."
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
    "my.app": "./",
    "my.library": "/resources/library",
    "library": "/resources/library"
  }'
  ...
></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a year I just find out the root cause of the issue which was affecting only a small amount of files in our project: somewhere in old legacy code was hidden this line

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath('my.library', '/onlinepath/to/my/library');
```

This line was overriding all my efforts to use local library files, pointing explicitly to their online version.